# I can't get my Django URLs to work

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

My code is as follows:

root urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('app.urls')),
]
```

My applications url is like so

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^homepage/$', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
]
```

The first screen the user will see is the login screen (views.login). At the moment I just want to set the login button to be a url that takes them to the homepage (just for practice) but it doesnt seem to work.

The login html is like so

```
<button type="button"><a href="{% url 'homepage' %}">Log-In</a></button>
```

This should go to my urls page above...find the name 'homepage' and take me to views.homepage which is as so:

```
def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'application/homepage.html', {})
```

but my homepage doesnt get rendered and I have absolutely no idea why its driving me crazy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there an error being shown?

Comment: Nothing. Its as if I just put in a button that wasn't a link. If I manually type in the URL then it goes to the views and renders properly so it makes me think the problem is in my login.html page and Im not writing the url properly.

Comment: The problem was solved below. Thanks for your help but my problem lay in making a button a link. It was a pure html issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Django, but a pure HTML problem. You can't put a link inside a button. A button needs to be part of a form, and submits to the `action` value of that form. Either do that, and take the `a` tag out; or, remove the button, and just use the a.